# Play Framework Regex CORS

Tags: playframework, cors, playframework-2.4

I implemented CORS in Play framework by populating play.filters.cors in application.conf
For the allowedOrigins parameter I will need to allow all subdomains from a specific domain. Can I use something like this:

```
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = ["*.domain1.com", "*.domain2.com"]
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 1 day
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in CORS filter doen't allow what you want to do. See the line pour understand how the origin is checked https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7c9f340aff786e945661bf34b169632f39896d8d/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/cors/AbstractCORSPolicy.scala#L312.

You can certainly create a custom CORSFilter by extending AbstractCORSPolicy and overriding this method.